# MissingTranslationData - How do you set the TranslationData?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, translation

When posting from the [has_calendar](http://github.com/fnando/has_calendar) plugin, there is a request for the TranslationData. I'm not sure what this is, or how to set it (or where to set it).

Here's the error it's spitting out.

```
translation missing: en, date, formats, day_of_week
```

Is there somewhere I need to set the locale for the calendar? The plugin doesn't give any instructions about the translation data, so I think this is Rails-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need define the key in your config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      day_of_week: "Day of week"
```